# php_memcache.dll not working in latest wampserver 2.5

Tags: php

PHP Mamcached (php_memcache.dll) dll not working in Latest wampserver 2.5.i have got

> "Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found".

I have referred http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache/3.0.8/windows these link but i have not found any solution.

Other links

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php
- http://www.9lessons.info/2012/02/memcached-with-php.html
- http://stannesi.blogspot.in/2011/11/how-to-install-memcache-on-xampp.html
- http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/

Comment: have you tried starting up your wampserver with startup errors enabled (`display_startup_errors`), so you can see any errors related to extensions on startup? If not, try that.

Comment: The module is enabled in php.ini right? i.e. `extension=php_memcache.dll`

Comment: I do that but not working it display "Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found". these error